# Let's assume you are writing cognito like user pool on DynamoDB, how would you partition it to span it to multiple companies?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Say we will have a Users table in dynamodb. But we will have multiple companies using this service. Each company could have millions of users. So having a companyId as partition wouldn't work. Similarly having a companyId as a sparse index wouldn't work. How would you partition a table to serve multiple different companies?

I guess the real question is how would you write a service on DynamoDB which will work as SaaS for many different customers? How to separate customers data on DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be for each user you would have a compound partition key that is made up of the companyID and the userID. So like this:

12554::baranbaygan

That way any time you need something from that user, the application has these values and can concatenate them and can immediately get that user's item or items with a GetItem or Query.

Then you could add a sort key for the table of something else. How you ultimately model this really will depend on the access patterns you plan to support with this application.